# Read specific area of tif image

Tags: java, qr-code, image-recognition

Have one tif image which contains QR code on the top right. Now I want to read only that corner of Image using java. I am trying with `FileInputStream` but it's not working.

Is any one knows how to read specific area of Image using java?

Comment: The Tif file format is quite complex so you will need to use a library which understands the format.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a specific portion from an image is basically *more complex* than just reading the entire image. Just read the image normally (JAI handles TIF: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html) and copy the desired portion into a new image if needed.

Comment: I just forget to mention that while reading tif Image, I am converting that image in PNG and after that I am reading that Image. It's working fine when I reading full Image. But I want to read only part of image.